# Windows App (One Click) Vs Web App

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

We are moveing our old Access VBA / SQL 2005 application to new technologys and have 2 options do we build a Windows Form Application with Microsoft One Click Deploy or a ASP.Net Website?

The application is a work force mangement system booking jobs dynamic scheduling gantt chart components. It will be used by 400 + Users over 20 Locations.

Can you give me some feedback on these options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the application to be maintained in one central location and accessed by the users over the web...go with a web application. If your team is more familiar with Windows Form applications, there's going to be a learning curve involved with this option (maintaining state, dynamic controls, page events, the DOM, etc.) so the time investment is going to be greater.

If you want the clients to have a rich interface installed on the desktops that you can manage easily from a central location...go with Windows Forms (or WPF to provide a nicer user experience). **Using ClickOnce for deployment will make sure that the client applictions stay up to date.** It sounds like this would be the more familiar option for your team and produce the best product in the shortest amount of time.

If your users are all inside your corporate network, either option can use a central SQL Server database (or shared Access/SQL Server Compact Edition/SQLLite database).

Don't get caught up in the hype. Web appilcations aren't always the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the infomation, 90% of the users will be inside our network but some outside the network. I was thinking about using webservices for the app to get/send data. Comments??

Comment: Web Services are definitely a good way to architect things. Just make sure that if there's confidential information going across the wire...you check out WS-Security and protect the data.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a web application.  This will provide the benefits of a central location to manage.  With 400+ users and 20 locations a windows app will take more time and headaches for updates and maintenance.

Comment: But with using Windows Forms with One Click would make the data central and the app would always be up todate as i understand one click would manage this. Comments??

Comment: @MartGriff: the above answer doesn't take into account ClickOnce.  ClickOnce is nearly headache free, makes it easy to support thousands of desktops, and requires almost no new skills for your WinForms developers.

Answer (score 2):

Provided all your users have good bandwidth to the hosting site (10mb at least) then the port route to a Click-once app is probably the easiest, and should give your users the shortest learning curve.

Comment: We would host the data from a data center (100mb) and the sites have 8mb ADSL connection

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at silverlight as an option?  This will give you the benefits of a web application but will allow you to create a richer UI.

Comment: Correct Silverlight would improve this but my problem is time as non of my team have used silverlight yet. How easy is it to pickup/use?

Comment: I have had no problems picking it up so far.  But I have only done evaluation and learning projects.

Answer (score 2):

I have deployed a ClickOnce app to over 110 locations with 500-600 users, and ClickOnce does a nice job handling deployment, maintenance and updates.  A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. ClickOnce apps still are software running on users' machines rather than in a browser, so even though in most cases it is just as easy to support as a Web app, there will be occasional maintenance problems you won't normally have to support with a Web app (corrupt registry, local machine security snafus, hard drive issues, etc.).  You also have to maintain certificates for the ClickOnce assembly permissions, which is an additional area of administration/support.
2. With the advent and gradual maturing of Silverlight and better AJAX tooling, the UI gap between Windows and Web is getting smaller and smaller
3. The bigger your app gets, downloading of updates can take some time, particularly at remote locations that may not have the fastest network access speeds.

You will need to weigh the benefits of deploying a Windows solution over a new Web one; in our case, the application we were replacing was a Windows app, and we wanted to reproduce a lot of the screens and workflow to look/act the same as the older version for productivity and training purposes, so we picked ClickOnce.  I don't have any regrets, ClickOnce worked well for us.

Comment: Thats for that information, given me a few things to think about ;-)